# Translate coordinates relative to obj1 to be relative to obj2

Tags: lua, tabletop-simulator

I have an object (`obj1`) that creates a button.

```lua
self.createButton({ position={ 15.7, 0.1, -1.8 }, ...})
```

That position, of course, is relative to `obj1`.

`obj1` is a bag, and the button it creates is on the game board, far away from the bag (as you can tell by the magnitude of the X component). This isn't appropriate, and it means the bag can't be moved. I want to have the game board create the button instead.

How do I determine the coordinates to provide when calling `createButton` from within the game board (`obj2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out that one can translate the relative position to an absolute position using the following:

```lua
local rel_pos = Vector(15.7, 0.1, -1.8)
local abs_pos = Vector(-v[1], v[2], v[3])
abs_pos:scale( obj1.getScale() )
abs_pos:rotateOver('z', obj1.getRotation()['z'] )  -- The order is important
abs_pos:rotateOver('x', obj1.getRotation()['x'] )
abs_pos:rotateOver('y', obj1.getRotation()['y'] )
abs_pos:add( obj1.getPosition() )
```

Reversing the process using `obj2` will get the vector to use in `obj2`.

---

But why is the X component negated? I thought I was missing something until I discovered `positionToWorld`, a function meant to do exactly what the above attempts. It turns out I still needed to negate the X component.

```lua
local rel_pos = Vector(15.7, 0.1, -1.8)
local abs_pos = obj1.positionToWorld(Vector(-v[1], v[2], v[3]))
```

I can only conclude that that `createButton` has a bug that requires one to negate the X component of the `position` it is provided.

---

The following is the complete solution:

```lua
local v = Vector(15.7, 0.1, -1.8)
v:setAt(1, -v[1])             -- Bug-compensated loc rel to obj1 -> Loc rel to obj1
v = obj1.positionToWorld(v)   -- Loc rel to obj1 -> Absolute loc
v = obj2.positionToLocal(v)   -- Absolute loc -> Loc rel to obj2
v:setAt(1, -v[1])             -- Loc rel to obj2 -> Bug-compensated loc rel to obj2
print(logString(v))
```

---

The final result was replacing

```lua
-- In obj1 (the bag)
self.createButton({ position={ 15.7, 0.1, -1.8 }, ... })
```

with

```lua
-- In obj2 (the game board)
self.createButton({ position={ -7.745875, 13.7634, -1.006971 }, ... })
```